# How can I auto-update Text according to fetched value from Database using Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sqflite

I fetched counting of a total number of records from `Sqflite database` and I display it on the Dashboard page but records counting is not increased when new record added, need to reopen the page to view changes? So how can I make it auto-update when a new record added?

Databse

```
Future<int> getSubCount() async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $subTable"));
  }
```

```
int subjects;

void _getCount() async {
    final int count = await db.getSubCount();
    setState(() {
      subjects = count;
    });
  }
```

Text Field

```
                    Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                  padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 5),
                                  child: Text("Subjects",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black54))),
                              Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                  child: Text("$subjects",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          fontSize: 16))),
                            ],
                          ),
```

Comment: You can call this "_getCount()" method when you added in database. not working then share your database added method.

Comment: It is working properly

Comment: It seems that your code is right. but make sure you have use "StateFullWidget". As you want to show the value from db again in the Text, you must have to create a StateFullWidget so that, on calling setState() it will get re rendered and updated value will be shown.

Comment: @ArwyShelke I already using ```StateFullWidge```.

Comment: Then dont use Future, try Calling getSubCount() on pressing the insertRecordButton once you done with inserting the record.

Comment: @ArwyShelke the flow is I added record, record is saved into database then i pop on list-View Page, when I move from list-View page back then dashboard page display here counting is displaying .